# What type of MOSFET is this

Tags: mosfet

Hey so I was able to conduct a wireless powered experiment, using a power MOSFET. The range of the electromegnetic field was amazing. Truly beautiful.  Anyway so I found this MOSFET and I was like cool I will try using that instead of am npn type resistor for the wireless transfer. It work! 
The thing is I think I might have blown the MOSFET because now the electromegnetic range is quite low. I had 12 volts going through that power MOSFET.  I thought those things could withstand volts up to 120. Anyway I didn't use a transistor, and the MOSFET heated up like crazy, I think I could have cooked an egg on it. Anyway back to business; I have a few questions concerning this MOSFET which are listed below.

1. The MOSFET has these numbers listed on the front. 04n60c3

**Picture of MOSFET**

[image: MOSFET PICTURE]

**My question (s)**

1. What type of MOSFET this
2. How much power can I give it
3. Can I have a diagram of this MOSFET?

**Other**

I have the video of the MOSFET in action. Note that the range had decreased before the video.

[Video of MOSFET transfering power wirelessly](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=YuZ5hhdwLdQ)

Comment: Looks like LOTS of wire to me....

Comment: The wires are connected from the coil to the LED.

Comment: Ya so.. it's just a transformer, and not a very good one..

Comment: Ugh. Air core. Ferrite sheets..please. "The one in the video blew cuz I didn't do math".

Comment: Lol yes that what I said to my friend. , It was like 12 midnight

Comment: @Trevor it is a great transformer, the range of the MOSFET when I first tested was 6 feet. No one has ever reached that range yet!(using a transistor)

Comment: Doubles as a jammer.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Ok who just down vote that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a 650V n-channel power MOSFET by Infineon. Datsheet [here](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/SPP_A04N60C3_Rev.3.0.pdf?folderId=db3a304412b407950112b408e8c90004&fileId=db3a304412b407950112b42dd6a14900). The datasheet has answers to questions of voltage and power. This is the 'FP' (full pack) isolated package.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like those though, what's with the metal thing on the back.

Comment: If it's a 650v why would 12v kill it. Or cause it to turn into 1950s stove top?

Comment: Too much power dissipation causing destructive heating is a rather likely cause but there are many ways to wreck things.

Comment: @GovaDEster How much current... must have been quite a bit to power that coil

Comment: 12v from a DC power supply

Comment: @GovaDEster that's not current...........

Comment: @Trevor is it true that the more rounds I have of a coil, the greater the electromegnetic field?

Comment: @GovaDEster more ampere-turns yes. More turns does not necessarily mean that though. As you increase the length of the wire the resistance goes up and amps goes down.

Comment: @Trevor so does the size of the magnet wire matter too. I would think so cuz that means the resistance also goes up. I need to create a coil that will send out an electromegnetic field and I need the range of the field to increase.

Comment: @GovaDEster thicker wire means you can have more turns for the same resistance yes. and vica-versa

Comment: @Trevor one more question, does the diameter of the coil matter significantly.  I know a 20 mile coil will output different from a 200 mile one, but I am talking in small terms like inches.

Comment: After that I will stop asking. 

Comment: The diameter of the coil affects the magnetic flux density inside the coil circle and how far it projects out in each direction in space. It is a complicated formula though. A small coil produces a strong field in the axis direction, while a big coil generates a more spread out field in all directions.

Comment: @GovaDEster YVW..  I'll send you my bill.. ;)

Comment: @Trevor im not sure how much current the coil drew just that I gave it 12v.